# Depth calculation for 3D-2D projections with different intrinsics and extrinsic matrices

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, computer-vision

I have an ikea manual and the 3D parts in the assembled state. For each step in the ikea manual I have calculated intrinsic and extrinsic matrices to project the part onto the manual. Currently the intrinsic is different for each part and it is my understanding that this is unavoidable as the manual steps are drawn and thus each part might have individual scaling and distortion, which is something that cannot be encoded just in the extrinsics.d

Projecting the parts on the manual already works reasonable well, but the problem is handling occlusions. If my understanding is correct, then techniques like z-buffering would work well if one intrinsic was used for all the parts. But with different intrinsics it doesn't work, i.e. different focal length will change the z-axis for instance.

To provide some sample code:

```py
def _get_mask_part(self, path: pathlib.Path, extrinsic: Float[np.ndarray, "4 4"], intrinsic: Float[np.ndarray, "3 3"], height: int,width: int) -> Tuple[Bool[np.ndarray, "height width"], Float[np.ndarray, "height width"]]:
        """
        Uses trimesh and pyrender to load the mesh of the specific parts, applies all transformations, puts camera in scene
        and finally projects and renders the scene onto an image to finally obtain bitmasks for parts. 

        Args:
            path: Path to the mesh .obj file of this part. 
            extrinsic: Extrinsic transformation of this part. 
            intrinsic: Intrinsic transformation of this part. 
            height: Height of the manual image.
            width: Width of the manual image.

        Returns: 
            Tuple consisting of the bitmask of the specific part in image plane and pixel depth information of this part which will be used for mean depth calculation.
        """

        scene = pyrender.Scene(ambient_light=[0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0], bg_color=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0])
        fuze_trimesh = trimesh.load(path, force='mesh')

        mesh = pyrender.Mesh.from_trimesh(fuze_trimesh)

        scene.add(mesh, pose=extrinsic)

        fx, fy, cx, cy = intrinsic[0, 0], intrinsic[1, 1], intrinsic[0, 2], intrinsic[1, 2]
        camera = pyrender.IntrinsicsCamera(fx=fx, fy=fy, cx=cx, cy=cy, znear=0.05, zfar=100)

        camera_pose = np.eye(4)
        camera_pose[1][1] = -1
        scene.add(camera, pose=camera_pose)

        renderer = pyrender.OffscreenRenderer(viewport_height=height, viewport_width=width)
        _, depth = renderer.render(scene)

        # for now rough calibration of pixel depth with focal length
        depth = 1000 / fx * depth
        mask = depth != 0
        renderer.delete()

        return mask, depth
```

This will be done for each part and then a mean depth is calculated based on the non zero pixels, which is used for sorting the parts:

```py
mean_depth = np.mean(depth[depth != 0])
```

As you can see I do some rough estimate by multiplying the depth with the focal length to account for different focal length. The results look okayish, but there are plently of failure cases.

So my question is:

1. Given this setup with different intrinsics and extrinsics, is it possible to correctly calculate the depth? (Note: In case it matters, the assumption that all parts are in a specific order seem to hold, but ideally it would also work on pixel level)
2. Is there some other method using something different than intrinsics and extrinsics for this. It would be possible for me to annotate say keypoints in 2D and 3D to calculate something useful (Currently I do PnP to estimate the intrinsics / extrinsics)

In case it is needed: This is the original dataset being used [https://cs.stanford.edu/~rcwang/projects/ikea_manual/](https://cs.stanford.edu/%7Ercwang/projects/ikea_manual/)

Comment: Does depth go from 0 to 1 in your case? before multiplying or anything, right at the output of renderer.render()

Comment: No, the depth can go above 1. So the lowest is always zero, the max value is depending on the part something between 5 and 30.

Comment: This is a cool problem. Solving the problem may require reasoning about 3D shapes (e.g. convex hulls with deficits) in which each shape has an adjustable scaling parameter to test matches. Mean depth for sorting may be too simplistic. Identify corners, but of polygons / polyhedra. Rectangle detection could be useful.  For inspiration, read about functional recognition--see 1990s papers especially. The book Making a Machine That Sees Like Us by Pizlo et al. is a bit weird but may be useful.